# How to change theme/design for one page?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, branding, design

I have a main page in SharePoint.Then I create a subpage that is a wiki.

Now I want to use another design template for just this page?

When I preview, it looks like it will change the whole main page as well.
How to make sure the template is only applied on a specific page?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Site Settings from the new Wiki sub site
2. Under Look and Feel, select "Change the Look"
3. Select new look

The new window that opens will state at the top with a yellow ribbon "This site is set to inherit the look from its parent site. Applying changes will break this inheritance." So this sub site and all sub sites under this site will have this unique look while the rest of the site keeps the original look.